# Using NSTimer as "delay" in AppleScriptObjc

Tags: cocoa, delay, nstimer, applescript-objc

I'm trying to use NSTimer as "delay" in AppleScript, in other words, I want to use NSTimer for only waiting.

```
on buttonClicked_(sender)
    log "Button is clicked"
    NSTimer's scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval_target_selector_userInfo_repeats_(60, me, "timerFired:", "Whatever", false) -- I want to make this line work like "delay 60"!
    log "Finished"
end buttonClicked_

on timerFired_(theTimer)
    log "Timer Fired"
end timerFired_
```

However, this code outputs following:

```
: Button is clicked
: Finished
: Timer Fired
```

This occurred because NSTimer starts but doesn't wait for a next operation.

```
on buttonClicked_(sender)
    log "Button is clicked"
    delay 60
    log "Finished"
end buttonClicked_

on timerFired_(theTimer)
    log "Timer Fired"
end timerFired_
```

After all, I want to substitute "delay" for "NSTimer" without changing the format.

Comment: Hi, what's the advantage of using NSTimer in place of delay?

Comment: on on buttonClicked_(sender) is this right?  To write "on" twice?  Maybe this is a typo, or maybe it's something that I don't know about.

Comment: NSTimer is superior to delay in having "theTimer's invalidate()". And it was mistake. Sorry. I edited.